# Creating recursive function to find object with certain attribute value

Tags: python

I have a list of objects based on:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,name):
         self.name = name
         self.children = [] #other instances contained in this list
```

I have created a function that will find the object when `.name` matches the search term and will search through all the children of these objects:

```
def find(lst,search_term):
    for obj in lst:
        if obj.name == search_term:
            return obj
        elif obj.children != []:
            try:
                if find(obj.children,search_term).name == search_term:
                    return find(obj.children,search_term)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: can you create a `FooChild` class which inherits from the `Foo` class?  This way you would only have to check the `name` attr with one for-loop.

Comment: @jeschwar that would prohibit grand children ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "normal" base case is fine.
Your "failure" base case should be explicit:

```
for obj in lst:
    if obj.name == search_term:
        return obj
    else:
        ...
# If all searches failed
return None
```

Your recursion step has redundant work: (1) you test the name of the returned object, when you already know it matches; (2) you recur twice with identical data.  Try streamlining the logic: iterate through the `obj` list until you find a match.

```
    else:
        if obj.children:
            found_child = find(obj.children,search_term)
            if found_child:
                return found_child
```

This code goes in place of the ellipsis in the above block.

Answer (score 0):

It's often easier to divide these types of problems into two functions, one for finding in a list and one for finding in a node. The finding in a node function is trivial (either it's the correct node or try to find in the children):

```
def _find_node(node, search_term):
    if node.name == search_term:
        return node
    return _find_list(node.children, search_term)
```

the finding in a list function then just calls `_find_node` on each item (and returns the node if it's found):

```
def _find_list(lst, search_term):
    for node in lst:
        found = _find_node(node, search_term)
        if found is not None:
            return found
    return None
```

Note that `None` is explicitly returned when not found.